# How can I make "Never" exclusive from all the rest of options in the same row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make "Never" exclusive from all the rest of options in the same row ("Never" cannot be selected along with another option in the same row);
and make "Less often", "Monthly" and "Weekly" exclusive each other (more than 1 of those cannot be selected on the same row);

I could only make, at some point, only 3 of the first line to work but I could still select the weekdays while I've already selected Never or Less Often for example.

```html
    <html>

    <head>

    <title>Vlad</title>

    </head>

    <body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="70%" style="padding:20px">
    <td style="border:2px solid;padding:5px">
    <B>

    This assignment consists of the following tasks:
    <UL> 
    <LI> make "Never" exclusive from all the rest of options in the same row 
    ("Never" cannot be selected along with another option in the same row);
    <LI> make "Less often", "Monthly" and "Weekly" exclusive each other (more 
    than 1 of those cannot be selected on the same row);
    </UL></B>



     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr><tr><td>



     <B>Please indicate how often do you watch the following TV channels?</B>
     <form action="" name="form1">

     <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>

     <tr><td width=100px padding=10px align=center >&nbsp;</td><td 
     width=100px padding=10px align=center >&nbsp;</td><td width=100px 
     padding=10px align=center >&nbsp;</td><td width=100px padding=10px 
     align=center>Never</td><td width=100px padding=10px align=center>Less 
     often</td><td width=100px padding=10px align=center >Monthly</td><td 
     width=100px padding=10px align=center>Weekly</td><td width=100px 
     padding=10px align=center>Every Monday</td><td width=100px padding=10px 
     align=center>Every Tuesday</td><td width=100px padding=10px 
     align=center>Every Wednesday</td><td width=100px padding=10px 
     align=center>Every Thursday</td><td width=100px padding=10px 
     align=center>Every Friday</td><td width=100px padding=10px 
     align=center>Every Saturday</td><td width=100px padding=10px 
     align=center>Every Sunday</td><td width=100px padding=10px align=center 
     >&nbsp;</td></tr>
     <tr><td align=center>CNN</td><td align=center>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td 
     align=center>&nbsp;</td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__1__1"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__1__2"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__1__3"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__1__4"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__1__5"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__1__6"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__1__7"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__1__8"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__1__9"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__1__10"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__1__11"></td><td align=center>&nbsp;</td></tr>
     <tr><td align=center>BBC</td><td align=center>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td 
     align=center>&nbsp;</td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__2__1"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__2__2"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__2__3"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__2__4"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__2__5"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__2__6"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__2__7"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__2__8"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__2__9"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__2__10"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__2__11"></td><td align=center>&nbsp;</td></tr>
     <tr><td align=center>SBS</td><td align=center>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td 
     align=center>&nbsp;</td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__3__1"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__3__2"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__3__3"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__3__4"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__3__5"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__3__6"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__3__7"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__3__8"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__3__9"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__3__10"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__3__11"></td><td align=center>&nbsp;</td></tr>
     <tr><td align=center>RTL</td><td align=center>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td 
     align=center>&nbsp;</td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__4__1"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__4__2"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__4__3"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__4__4"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__4__5"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__4__6"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__4__7"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__4__8"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__4__9"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__4__10"></td><td align=center><input type=checkbox 
     name="JS3test2__4__11"></td><td align=center>&nbsp;</td></tr>
     </table>

     </form> 
    
     </td> 

     </tr>

     </table>

     </body>

     </html>
```

Comment: I don't know what you're asking, but if it's how to have only one option selected at a time, use radio inputs instead of checkboxes. [example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_radio)

Comment: Can you update the question to just give us a sample row, include the script you've tried, and make it run in a snippet on this page?  In other words, a [mcve]

Comment: I don't want to use radio inputs, I want to use checkboxes and make the first 4 from each column (Never, Les often, Monthly and Weekly) exclusive from the others (Every Monday, Every Tuesday and so on). So you can't thick a "Never" checkbox, for example, and an "Every Monday" checkbox at the same time.

Comment: How will you process the result afterwards? And someone also should not select Monthly and Every Monday together, right?

Comment: For now I want to find a way to do this. Exactly ! None of the first four (Never, Less often, Monthly and Weekly) can be selected with any of the weekdays, but you can select multiple weekdays only. So you either select one of the first four, either one or more weekdays.

Comment: Is this your school assignment? this is not cool to use this site for assignments.